# How to wrap lines in JUnit's Eclipse view Failure Trace

Tags: eclipse, junit, view, stack-trace, word-wrap

When working on a 17" laptop display sometimes there's not much space to arrange Eclipse's views with proper size. If there are long exception messages the need to scroll horizontally isn't too convenient.

As an alternative there's a tool called [MaxiVista](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1iUy9frSJq4) to extend the display to a second laptop but the `Maxivista_x64_Setup_PrimaryPC.exe` of the [(64-Bit) download of v4.0.12](https://www.netzwelt.de/software-chooser/4308-maxivista.html) results in "*This installation file is outdated.*" on my Win7 Prof.

Another alternative, [spacedesk](https://spacedesk.net/multi-monitor-app-virtual-display-screen-software-video-wall), works but I still have to scroll horizontally even if the view is full-width on the second display.